# XCode 4.3 Storyboards: why are some UIViewControllers sized 1024 while others 320

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have just started playing with storyboards in XCode 4.3 and while designing an app where I wanted to create a master-detail controller like storyboard, I had the following object structure in a scene...

- UIViewController

  - UIView (container)
  - UITableView (master navigation menu)
  - UIView (search field)

    - UIImageView
    - UITextField

Now in this the `container` UIView scales to fill the complete UIViewController and has a default width/height 1024 x 748. Dragging and dropping a UITableViewController on canvas, it also has a default 1024 x 748 size. But upon dragging/dropping a UISplitViewController, the UITableViewController is sized 320 in width. How did that happen? How can I change my UIView to not be sized to fill the UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The master detail controller of a split view is of a fixed width (320). The detail view is either the full portrait width, or the remaining landscape width (full width less the detail width) if in landscape.